# Expo Google response.authentication is null

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, google-oauth

I am trying to create a React Native app with Expo and authenticate using google. I am following [this documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google). I expect `response.authentication.accessToken` to be a string access token, instead it is null. My error message is `Typeerror: null is not an object (evaluating 'response.authentication.accesstoken')`

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function App() {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = React.useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: "[REDACTED].apps.googleusercontent.com",
    webClientId: "[REDACTED].apps.googleusercontent.com",
    iosClientId: "[REDACTED].apps.googleusercontent.com",
    androidClientId: "[REDACTED].apps.googleusercontent.com",
  });

  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(response?.type === "success") {
      console.log(response);
      setAccessToken(response.authentication.accessToken);
      accessToken && fetchUserInfo();
    }
  }, [response, accessToken])
```

Why is it null?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to switch functions, Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest to Google.useAuthRequest. I also fixed my bundleIdentifier and android package in app.json to exactly match my slug (there were capitalization issues).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).